# Bundle cache-busters on a web server farm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, bundling-and-minification, web-farm

The [ASP.NET Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) tutorial states:

> The query string v has a value token that is a unique identifier used
>   for caching. As long as the bundle doesn't change, the ASP.NET
>   application will request the AllMyScripts  bundle using this token. If
>   any file in the bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework
>   will generate a new token, guaranteeing that browser requests for the
>   bundle will get the latest bundle.

How does this work on a web server farm?

If I update a javascript file included in a bundle, will the new query string be the same across my web farm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `v` query string is just a hash of the contents of that bundle. If the same set of Javascript files are deployed to all servers in your farm, the hash should be the same, resulting in a the same `v` value on all servers.

Comment: Thanks Steven, do you have a reference for this information?

Comment: @Curt I don't have an authoritative source on the internet. But you can look at the source code of the assembly in a disassembler and you can see it uses SHA256 upon the contents of the bundle.